# Python remove space from string make it into int

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium

How would I remove the space in `<span id="balance">1 268</span>` and make it an `int`

Code:

```
    Balance_afterWinORLoseBet.replace(" ", "")
    Balance_afterWinORLoseBet = int(balance_new.text) #Makes new var, turns it into int.


if "10.1" in countdown_timer.text: #
    Balance_afterPlaceBet.replace(" ", "")
    Balance_afterPlaceBet = int(balance_old.text) #Makes new var, turns it into int.
```

`Error`:

> Balance_afterWinORLoseBet = int(balance_new.text) #Makes new var, turns it into int.
>       ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 268'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the other answers explain why your code doesn't work. The reason is that `.replace()` does not change the original variable, but returns ["a copy of string s with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace).

Example

```
>>> Balance_afterWinORLoseBet = "1 268"
>>> Balance_afterWinORLoseBet.replace(" ", "")
'1268'
>>> Balance_afterWinORLoseBet
'1 268'
```

Answer (score 0):

int(balance_new.text.replace(" ",""))

Comment: Code only answers are strongly discouraged. Please add some description of what the code is doing and how it answers the question. Also, format your code as code.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this. It will work for all whitespace characters.

```
int("".join(balance_new.text.split()))
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you want the final output to be, '1268', and do not want to convert the entire string with HTML tags to 'int' type.

With this assumption, you can try this:

`myvar = '<span id="balance">1 268</span>'
print int(myvar.replace(" ", "").split('>')[1].split('<')[0])`